# How do I detach/close JavaDStream and TwitterUtils.createStream(...)

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have an SPARK application that uses TwitterUtils to read a Twitter stream and uses a map and a foreachRDD on the stream to put Twitter messages into a database. That all works great.

My question: What is the most appropriate way to detach from the Twitter stream once everything is running. Suppose I want to only collect 1000 messages or run the collection for 60 seconds.

The code is as follows:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Java spark twitter stream");
JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(1000));
JavaDStream<Status> tweets = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, filters);

JavaDStream<String> statuses = tweets.map(
        new Function<Status, String>() {
            public String call(Status status) {
                //combine the strings here.
                GeoLocation geoLocation = status.getGeoLocation();
                if (geoLocation != null) {
                    String text = status.getText().replaceAll("[\r\n]", " ");
                    String line = geoLocation.getLongitude() + ",,,,"
                           + geoLocation.getLatitude() + ",,,,"
                           + status.getCreatedAt().getTime()
                           + ",,,," + status.getUser().getId()
                           + ",,,," + text;
                    return line;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        ).filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call(String input) {
                return input != null;
            }
        });
        statuses.print();


statuses.foreachRDD(new Function2<JavaRDD<String>, Time, Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd, Time time) {
            SQLContext sqlContext 
                     = JavaSQLContextSingleton
                           .getInstance(rdd.context());
            sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.tungsten.enabled", "false");

            JavaRDD<Row> tweetRowRDD 
                     = rdd.map(new TweetMapLoadFunction());

            DataFrame statusesDataFrame 
                     = sqlContext
                            .createDataFrame(
                                tweetRowRDD,
                                tweetSchema.createTweetStructType());
            return null;
        }
    });

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is straight from **[the documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#initializing-streamingcontext)**:

> The processing can be manually stopped using streamingContext.stop().
>
> **Points to remember:**
>
> - Once a context has been started, no new streaming computations can be set up or added to it.
> - Once a context has been stopped, it cannot be restarted.
> - Only one StreamingContext can be active in a JVM at the same time.
> - stop() on StreamingContext also stops the SparkContext. To stop only the StreamingContext, set the optional parameter of stop() called stopSparkContext to false.
> - A SparkContext can be re-used to create multiple StreamingContexts, as long as the previous StreamingContext is stopped (without stopping the SparkContext) before the next StreamingContext is created.